# Image Viewer C# next Button

Tags: c#, image

Hi i'm doing a simple image viewer in C#. It has 3 button first button contain "Open" and the last two button is "Back and Next" and the picturebox. I'm done with the open button using OpenFileDialog Here's my code in OpenFiledialog:

```
 private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg|Bitmaps|*.bmp";

        if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Now this is the problem i don't have idea what code can i use the in "next and back" button. i know it's looping. Need you're help guys thank you..

Comment: You can take all names of images from directory and put them into array. and then use id in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's working user control code. You'll need to create new Window Forms Application, create user control called MyPictureViewer. Add pictureBox, and 3 buttons to this control.
Paste below code to this usercontrol codebehind, hook click events, and add this control to main form. Hope this helps

```
public partial class MyPictureViewer : UserControl
{
    protected string[] pFileNames;
    protected int pCurrentImage = -1;

    public MyPictureViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void btnPrevImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pFileNames.Length > 0)
        {
            pCurrentImage = pCurrentImage == 0 ? pFileNames.Length - 1 : --pCurrentImage;
            ShowCurrentImage();
        }
    }

    void btnNextImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pFileNames.Length > 0)
        {
            pCurrentImage = pCurrentImage == pFileNames.Length - 1 ? 0 : ++pCurrentImage;
            ShowCurrentImage();
        }
    }

    private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg|Bitmaps|*.bmp";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pFileNames = openFileDialog.FileNames;
            pCurrentImage = 0;
            ShowCurrentImage();
        }
    }

    protected void ShowCurrentImage()
    {
        if (pCurrentImage >= 0 && pCurrentImage <= pFileNames.Length - 1)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(pFileNames[pCurrentImage]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sir is the're a code that it will resize the pictures in the picture box

Comment: PictureBox has property [SizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) which you could use. You can create new image with custom size from another image or if you need more advanced transformations for your images, you will have to get pixel array from image and work on that.

Answer (score 3):

You need some kind of enumeration of files. One way is to allow the user to select multiple files in the `OpenFileDialog.Multiselect` property. `OpenFileDialog` exposes a property Files that contains all the selected file names.

```
class MyPictureViewer
{
   protected string[] pFileNames;
   protected int pCurrentImage = -1;

   private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg|Bitmaps|*.bmp";

        if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pFileNames = openFileDialog.FileNames;
            pCurrentImage=0;
            ShowCurrentImage();
        }
   }

   protected void ShowCurrentImage()
   {
      if(pCurrentImage >= 0 && pCurrentImage < pFileNames.Length-1)
      {
          pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(pFileNames[pCurrentImage]);
      }
   }
}
```

You can implement event handlers for the click event of you next and previos either checking borders (so once you reach the last image you don't go beyond it) or cycling (if the user clicks Next on the last image, jump to the first)

```
void btnNextImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ++pCurrentImage;
        //check if this was last image in list
        if(pCurrentImage >= pFileNames.Length)
            pCurrentImage = pFileNames.Length == 0? -1 : 0;//if this was last image, go to first image
        ShowCurrentImage();
    }

void btnPrevImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        --pCurrentImage;
        //check if this was first image in list
        if (pCurrentImage < 0)
            pCurrentImage = pFileNames.Length == 0 ? -1 : pFileNames.Length -1;//if this was first image, go to last image
        ShowCurrentImage();
    }
```

Comment: @Ecarri sir i try to use you're codes but it not display the image thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here what I did for "btnPrevImage" is some how easier:

*// this button is forward button* 

private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(currentIndex!=imageList1.Images.Count-1 && imageList1.Images.Count > 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[currentIndex++];
        }

    }

*// this button is for Previews button*  

private void btnPrevImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentIndex!=0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[--currentIndex];
        }


do not forget to declare currentIndex.
```